# Getting DataPoint with mouse X coordinate only

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, charts

I need to access the `DataPoint` via X coordinate, but I can't seem to find any solutions for it. `HitTest()` is out, since it also needs Y coordinate (cannot hit anything if Y is 0). I know I could select the DataPoints via Linq and the X coordinate, but I was wondering if there are better solutions for this?

More specifically I'm trying to show Candlestick data (Open, Low, High, Close and DateTime) with a TextAnnotation, which follows the CursorX (it's anchored above my X-axis, which is located at the bottom of my chart), and my CursorX is intervalled so it is always in the center of a candle.

What I have so far, is a `MouseMove` function, which updates my `CursorX`, but lacks the data access and label update:

```
PointF _mouse = new PointF();
TextAnnotation _mouseLabel;
void UpdateMouseCursor(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if( _mouseLabel == null )
        return;

    _mouse.X = e.Location.X;
    _mouse.Y = e.Location.Y;

    var cursorX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX;

    cursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition( _mouse, true );
    _mouseLabel.X = cursorX.Position;
}
```

`CursorX` and `_mouseLabel` setup:

```
public void SetupMouse(double interval, DateTimeIntervalType intervalType)
{
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IntervalType = intervalType;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval = interval;

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 128,128,128);

    if( _mouseLabel == null )
    {
        _mouseLabel = new TextAnnotation();
        _mouseLabel.Text = "WOOHOO!";
        _mouseLabel.AnchorY = 85;
        _mouseLabel.AxisX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
        chart1.Annotations.Add( _mouseLabel );
    }
}
```

The visuals:
[image]

Comment: This is hardly possible since in most chart types, candlestick inluding, more that one data point may sit on the same x-value. So searching through the x-values to find a hit will be your best choice, I'm afraid. Since you will be calling it from a MOuseMove calling PixelToValue will work and if you really always hit the center of a candle you may create a Dictionary<double, DataPoint> for fast access..

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I went with Linq and it works fine. I hit the dead-center of a candle so I can pick them out with the exact X-value, it seems. I guess this is the solution I'm falling in to...